# multiple models in one form only one is required

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I have two models, one view and one form. all the fields are required in both models. but, I want the user to be able to fill up the first model's fields without require filling the second model's fields as long as the fields are all empty.
**models.py** :

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Kid(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**views.py**

```
def add_family(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parent_form = ParentForm(request.POST)
        kid_form = KidForm(request.POST)
        if parent_form.is_valid() and kid_form.is_valid():
            parent = parent_form.save(commit=False)
            parent.save()
            kid = kid_form.save(commit=False)
            kid.family = parent
            kid.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        parent_form = ParentForm()
        kid_form = KidForm()
        template = 'add_family.html'
        context = {'parent_form': parent_form, 'kid_form': kid_form}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

**template**:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ parent_form.title }}
    {{ parent_form.address }}
    {{ kid_form.title }}
    {{ kid_form.age }}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

and ideas?

Comment: have a look at [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/) for your kid form(s).

Comment: isn't there a way to do it other than formsets?